# Tomcat integration in Eclipse with maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to integrate Maven to my web project. I want t run project with mvn tomcat7:run, but  when I do it maven creates new tomcat configuration in MyProject/target/tomcat and when I'm trying to open it on localhost  and there is 404 error. Can anybody describe me  what I should do to configurate maven to use local preconfigured tomcat instance?

Answer (score 1):

Maven creates a Tomcat configuration locally with `mvn tomcat7:run` because you are running the webapp out of the `/target` directory and the aim is to keep the running webapp isolated from any external configuration. For example if you required custom Tomcat configuration applying then Maven would need to modify the Tomcat conf beforehand. This might not be possible due to file system permission or could affect other webapps. So Maven copies the config locally, applies any custom configuration and starts Tomcat via the `tomcat7-maven-plugin`.

One option is to look at the [**maven-cargo-plugin**](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) which can deploy a `.war` built with Maven into an existing running Tomcat installation. With the correct [**configuration**](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide), instead or using `mvn tomcat7:run` you would use `mvn cargo:redeploy` to remove a running webapp and replace it with your freshly built webapp.

As an alternative Eclipse can be configured to start a Tomcat instance in which to run the webapp in. If you change the Eclipse project type to a [Dynamic Web Project](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html) and then add a Tomcat instance to Eclipse by doing:

- Window → Preferences → Server → Runtime Environments
- Add → Apache Tomcat v7.0

and point it do the Tomcat you downloaded. Eclipse will use this *external* Tomcat as a template to create an *internal* Tomcat configuration for your webapp. Lastly, the webapp needs to be configured to deploy the correct resources and libraries into Tomcat. By right clicking on the project root → Properties → Deployment Assembly, alter the list to match your resource locations. A standard set-up might look something like

```
/src/main/java       |   /WEB-INF/classes
/src/main/resources  |   /WEB-INF/classes
/src/main/webapp     |   /
Maven Dependencies   |   /WEB-INF/lib
```

Comment: Regarding the alternative : can you elaborate more on how?

Comment: Can you explain how to configure eclipse without cargo plugin? Actually I'm trying to understand why Maven creates TOmcat configuration in project target. As I understant it shouldn't do this.

Comment: Updated with more information on Tomcat Eclipse configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but I had the same configuration before and doesn't resolve the problem. When I run tomcat7:run local server doesn't start, but eclipse say that it is started.

Comment: Are you running it from the command line or from Eclipse by using Run -> Run As -> Run on Server. Sounds like Eclipse has already started Tomcat and you are attempting to run it again from Maven.

Comment: I'm running it from eclipse using Run->Run as..-> Maven build...-> tomcat7:run

Comment: So you are not using the Tomcat configured in Eclipse, you are always using the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` which will copy the config into `/target` as I described and then start Tomcat. You are not currently running Tomcat via Eclipse as you are not using `Run on Server`.

Comment: That's why there is a question: why would it need a goal? When I can use tomcat7:run and why I recieve an error 404 when I start tomcat with tomcat7:run?

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that it was a `404`. You can start with `tomcat7:run` but the webapp is not configured correctly. Either the URL you are entering is not mapped to a Controller or that the webapp context is incorrect. For example is the webapp served at the root `/` or a named context like `/my-webapp`

Comment: I don't fully understand what do you mean. I think if I have wrong configuration that Run as..-> Run on server also shoudn't work isn't it?

Comment: Also you can see my pom.xml here

Comment: Sorry I am not able to chat. Is it possible for you to zip your project or put the code online so I could see it?

Comment: There is a restriction to number of comments, that's why message abiut chat appears automatically and I did not write it. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836571/tomcat-7-with-vaadin-hibernate-eclipse-and-maven-3