# Tomcat 7 with Vaadin, Hibernate, Eclipse and Maven 3

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat7, maven-3, vaadin

I'm trying to integrate maven in my existing Vaadin project. There is several errors and weird things. First of all I can't understand what I should do to make tomcat instance used by maven is visible in eclipse. I mean that when I run tomcat7:run, Tomcat instance, preconfigured in eclipse, stays stoped. Also I can't understand which Tomcat instance maven uses and why it creates Tomcat configuration files in project folder, because when I'm trying to open application in browser after tomcat7:run I recieve error 404. 
By the way there are several questions about compilation of Vaadin widgets. I configured vaadin maven plugin and gwt maven plugin. When I'm running mvn gwt:compile it seems that everything is ok, but when I'm trying to compile Vaadin widgets using eclipse plugin I have the following error

```
Executing compiler with parameters [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java.exe, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Xss8M, -Xmx512M, -XX:MaxPermSize=512M, -classpath, C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:/Popov/Ohta/src/main/java;C:/Popov/Ohta/src/test/java;C:/Popov/Ohta/target/classes;C:/Popov/Ohta/target/test-classes;C:/Popov/newEclipse/eclipse/configuration/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse/download/gwt-dev/2.3.0/gwt-dev.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.1/gwt-user-2.1.1.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.8.2/vaadin-6.8.2.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/refresher/1.1.1/refresher-1.1.1.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/vaadin-colorpicker/1.1.0/vaadin-colorpicker-1.1.0.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0/gwt-user-2.3.0.jar;C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.8.8/vaadin-6.8.8.jar, -Dgwt.persistentunitcachedir=C:\Users\popov\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.ritmsoft.ohta.widgetset.OhtaWidgetset943bcbe5-0ae3-4759-b1c0-d878be4261f9, com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler, -war, src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets, -deploy, C:\Users\popov\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.ritmsoft.ohta.widgetset.OhtaWidgetset943bcbe5-0ae3-4759-b1c0-d878be4261f9, -extra, C:\Users\popov\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.ritmsoft.ohta.widgetset.OhtaWidgetset943bcbe5-0ae3-4759-b1c0-d878be4261f9, -localWorkers, 2, -logLevel, INFO, com.ritmsoft.ohta.widgetset.OhtaWidgetset]
Updating GWT module description file...
фев 12, 2013 7:36:08 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Widgetsets found from classpath:
    com.github.wolfie.refresher.RefresherApplicationWidgetset in jar:file:C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/refresher/1.1.1/refresher-1.1.1.jar!/
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.8.8/vaadin-6.8.8.jar!/
    com.vaadin.addon.colorpicker.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/popov/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/vaadin-colorpicker/1.1.0/vaadin-colorpicker-1.1.0.jar!/
    com.ritmsoft.ohta.widgetset.OhtaWidgetset in file://C/Popov/Ohta/src/main/java

фев 12, 2013 7:36:08 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Search took 24ms
Done.
Starting GWT compiler
Unknown argument: -war
Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0
GWTCompiler [-logLevel level] [-workDir dir] [-gen dir] [-style style] [-ea] [-XdisableClassMetadata] [-XdisableCastChecking] [-validateOnly] [-draftCompile] [-optimize level] [-compileReport] [-strict] [-out dir] [-localWorkers count] module[s] 

where 
  -logLevel               The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -workDir                The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
  -gen                    Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -style                  Script output style: OBF[USCATED], PRETTY, or DETAILED (defaults to OBF)
  -ea                     Debugging: causes the compiled output to check assert statements
  -XdisableClassMetadata  EXPERIMENTAL: Disables some java.lang.Class methods (e.g. getName())
  -XdisableCastChecking   EXPERIMENTAL: Disables run-time checking of cast operations
  -validateOnly           Validate all source code, but do not compile
  -draftCompile           Enable faster, but less-optimized, compilations
  -optimize               Sets the optimization level used by the compiler.  0=none 9=maximum.
  -compileReport          Create a compile report that tells the Story of Your Compile
  -strict                 Only succeed if no input files have errors
  -out                    The directory to write output files into (defaults to current)
  -localWorkers           The number of local workers to use when compiling permutations
and 
  module[s]               Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to compile
Widgetset compilation failed
```

Otherwise, if I compile widgets using mvn gwt:compile and after that build war using maven and deploy it I recieve en empty page in browser.
Also when I'm trying to run application as run on server I have the following exception

```
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Ohta' did not find a matching property.
фев 12, 2013 7:55:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Ohta]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 25 more

фев 12, 2013 7:55:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Popov\Soft\conf\Catalina\localhost\Ohta.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Ohta]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ritmsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ohta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Ohta</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution></execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>local_tomcat</server>
                    <path>/Ohta</path>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>s3cret</password>
                    <warFile> ${project.build.directory}/Ohta.war</warFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets/</webappDirectory>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k </extraJvmArgs>
                    <deploy>${project.build.directory}/gwt-tmp/</deploy>
                    <soyc>false</soyc>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
                    <optimizationLevel>9</optimizationLevel>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>webContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <warName>Ohta</warName>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>rg.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache
                            Tomcat v7.0</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-colorpicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>refresher</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-pre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Help me, please.

Comment: The unknown argument -war error looks like you're issuing an invalid command

Comment: What do you mean? I just execute tomcat7:run

Comment: You are supposed to execute tomcat7:run-war Note that there is no space between the run, the - and the war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386703/1465758

May be you must add the jar's in maven.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
mvn tomcat7:run-war
```

There must be no space in the arguments for maven.