# vaadin gwt compiler error unknown argument: -war

Tags: gwt, compilation, vaadin

I have a problem with my vaadin project - and as i am rather new to vaadin, i am not sure on how to solve it.

I would like to re-compile my widgetset, but even after customizing eclipse i get the same error message:

First it executes the compiler via command line 
Next it tells me that the widgetsets were found from a certain classpath (which still is correct) 
And after that, I get the following output:

```
17.09.2013 11:10:18 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Search took 16ms
Done.
Starting GWT compiler
Unknown argument: -war
Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0
```

So i have two questions:

1. How to solve this unkonwn argument problem?
2. Does it have any influence one my application?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with versions. The GWT, Eclipse plugin and Vaadin versions you are using do not work with each other. GWT 2.3.0 is quite old, it was released in May 2011. So you might want to upgrade your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The error is gone after I add the following jars to my project classpath (right click the project, "Build Path" - "Configure build path...", tab "Libraries and "Add JARs..."):

- gwt-dev.jar
- gwt-user.jar
- validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
- validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar